# Looking for correct way to use useState + count to add an item - nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently my code is working but I feel i'm not using the useState/useEffect the correct way for my end goal. So to father explain, I have a button with onClick in a different component, which is passing the state/count to another component "FlexContainer", in that component im using `.push` to add the component "FlexItem" each time the count increases (which is working). But what im trying to do now is add a button inside the "FlexItem" component, that when clicked it will remove one of the "FlexItem's" from the count. This is when I realized my `function displayFlexItem()` is probably not the best solution to use for what im trying to do.

Parent Component

```
export default function Post({ globalProps, sidebarProps }) {
  const [addFlexItem, setAddFlexItem] = useState(0)
  const [addFlexItemStyles, setFlexItemStyles] = useState('')
  
  return (
    <Layout globalProps={globalProps}>
      <main className={styles.container}>
        
        <FlexSidebar sidebarProps={sidebarProps} onClick={() => setAddFlexItem(addFlexItem + 1)} handleOnChange={(value) => setFlexItemStyles(value)} />

        <FlexContainer addFlexItem={addFlexItem} addFlexItemStyles={addFlexItemStyles} />
        
      </main>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

FlexContainer

```
const FlexContainer = ({ addFlexItem }) => {
  const [isaddFlexItem, setaddFlexItem] = useState(addFlexItem)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setaddFlexItem(addFlexItem)
  }, [addFlexItem])

  function displayFlexItem() {
    let flexitem = []
    for (let i = 0;i < isaddFlexItem;i++) {
      flexitem.push(
        <FlexItem key={i} itemCount={i} />
      )
    }
    return flexitem || null
  }

  return (
    <section className={styles.right_content} style={{ flexDirection: isaddFlexItemStyles, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
      {displayFlexItem()}
    </section>
  )

}
```

Comment: You can simply build the array of `<FlexItem>`s based on the property passed to `<FlexContainer>`. You don't need `useState` and `useEffect` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [addFlexItem, setAddFlexItem] = useState(0)
```

You only handle the count but not items, so you cannot check which item gets removed for state update.

You should use an array instead

```
const [addFlexItem, setAddFlexItem] = useState([])
```

For the count, you can use `addFlexItem.length` which is to get the array length matching with your count.

Furthermore, `useState` and `useEffect` values are always aligned with the upper component's `addFlexItem` values, so you don't need to use them, but if you want to update `addFlexItem` in `FlexContainer`, you can pass `setAddFlexItem` into `FlexContainer`.

```
//converted your display flex item to a component
const DisplayFlexItem = ({ flexItems, removeFlexItem }) => {
    return flexItems.map((item) => (<>
       <FlexItem key={item} itemCount={item} />
       <button onClick={() => { removeFlexItem(item) }}>Remove</button>
    </>))
}

const FlexContainer = ({ addFlexItem, setAddFlexItem, addFlexItemStyles }) => {

  return (
    <section className={styles.right_content} style={{ flexDirection: isaddFlexItemStyles, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
     <DisplayFlexItem flexItems={addFlexItem} removeFlexItem={(item) => {
        const newAddFlexItem = addFlexItem.filter((currentItem) => currentItem !== item)
        setAddFlexItem(newAddFlexItem)
     }}/>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Your `Post` component can be

```
let currentIndex = 0 //keep your index in track
export default function Post({ globalProps, sidebarProps }) {
  const [addFlexItem, setAddFlexItem] = useState([])
  const [addFlexItemStyles, setFlexItemStyles] = useState('')
  
  return (
    <Layout globalProps={globalProps}>
      <main className={styles.container}>
        
        <FlexSidebar sidebarProps={sidebarProps} onClick={() => setAddFlexItem([...addFlexItem, currentIndex++])} handleOnChange={(value) => setFlexItemStyles(value)} />

        <FlexContainer addFlexItem={addFlexItem} setAddFlexItem={setAddFlexItem} addFlexItemStyles={addFlexItemStyles} />
        
      </main>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

To add a new item to `addFlexItem`

```
setAddFlexItem([...addFlexItem, currentIndex++]) //increase your current index every time once the new item added
```

Comment: the `removeFlexItem` inside of `DisplayFlexItem` is missing some syntax, getting error `setAddFlexItem` is not a function. I thought it was just missing `{}` around the `const` and missing `/` at the end.

Comment: yupppp I missed `{}` there and just modified it! where is the missing `setAddFlexItem` you found in your development? @RobbieC

Comment: figured it out, was missing the semicolon before `setAddFlexItem(newAddFlexItem)`

Comment: I modified it earlier and checked syntax errors there, did you copy that part to your code again? @RobbieC